# document is not defined in React Native

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

I keep getting "document is not defined" in a React Native library.

But the thing is, I search the entire library, and don't see document anywhere.

The library is this, and it happens regardless of what version of the library I use:

https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars

I wouldn't come here, except that I've been stuck on this problem for like 5+ hours, with no end in sight.

I've been using this library for months in this build, I've tried reverting to older versions, and no luck. Whenever I try to do a build on iOS, it has issues with document.

```
  <CalendarList
    calendarWidth={320}
    height={320}
    theme={{ textDayFontSize: 16 }}
    style={{ borderRadius: 0 }}
    horizontal={horizontal}
    minDate={"2020-03-01"}
    maxDate={moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD")}
    pastScrollRange={5}
    futureScrollRange={5}
    showScrollIndicator={true}
    onDayPress={this.onDayPress}
    markedDates={this.state.dateRangeObj}
    markingType={"period"}
  />
```

[image: React Native library]

Answer (score 0):

This was apparently due to some weird interaction between Stripe and the React-Native-Calendars library, even though literally none of that code was interacting, it was in the same file (it was my file of various modals).

Moved to another file, worked.